# TSQLDataSet NoMetadata property does not exist error

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

While migrating a delphi 7 application to delphi XE4, I encountered an error: `property nometadata does not exist in TSQLDataset`.

When I compared the properties of `TSQLDataset` in delphi 7 and in delphi XE4, there is `NoMetadata` property in delphi 7 but no such property exists in delphi XE4.

So, should I remove `NoMetaData` property from delphi code to remove this error?

**Update:**

When I commented all `NoMetaData = True` lines in my delphi XE4 dfm file, I started to get following error:

```
unsupported 16bit resource file abc.dfm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem after some research. In delphi 7, `tsqldataset` has property `nometadata` which if set to true, no metadata is loaded. Similar property in delphi XE4 is `getmetadata` which if set to false, no metadata is loaded.

So, I replaced all `NoMetaData = True` lines to `GetMetadata = False` and error got resolved.